# Electron framework - From where electron downloads the new update

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am new to the electron framework.

I have a query where I need to deploy the new version for my app for mac and window?

Do I need to publish my application on some app stores?

I am working on a ToDo app, I have created `.exe` for the application, Now I want to make some changes to the app and let the app update automatically, for this where I need to upload my application?

Comment: You should refer https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish

Comment: Thank @MayankVadiya I am going through this link